# How to add elements of an array to another array and remove duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to create a json file in ruby on rails that has a specific format like so:

```
{"nodes":["1","2","3"],"edges":[["1","3"],["2","3"],["2","1"]]}
```

I have a method in my model that is as follows:

```
def self.joinup(id)
  c = Challenge.find(id)
  result={}
  user_ids  =  c.users.pluck(:id)
  result["nodes"] = user_ids.collect(&:to_s)
  result["edges"] = Relationship.where(follower_id: user_ids).map{|h| [h.follower_id.to_s, h.followed_id.to_s]}
  result["nodes"] = result["nodes"]|result["edges"]
  result
 end
```

and this produces:

```
{"nodes":["1","2","3","3","3"["4","5"],["5","6"]],"edges":[["4","5"],["5","6"]]}
```

whereas was I want is:

```
{"nodes":["1","2","3","4","5","6"],"edges":[["4","5"],["5","6"]]}
```

Comment: change this `user_ids.collect(&:to_s)` to this `user_ids.collect(&:to_s).flatten.uniq`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In rails you can use the array method **flatten** which returns an array with one dimension, like this

```
array = ["1", "2", "3", ["2", "3", "4"], "5"]
array.flatten #=> ["1", "2", "3", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

After that you can use the method **uniq** which returns all the different values inside your array, so this will return this as a result

```
array.flatten.uniq #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Also, this method can be used with the bang (!) operator, which change the original array with the return values, so it will be like this

```
array.flatten!.uniq!
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You merged the contents in `result["edges"]` in this line:

```
result["nodes"] = result["nodes"]|result["edges"]
```

after that, you may firstly `flatten` the array and then `uniq`:

```
result["nodes"].flatten!.uniq!
result
```

Comment: Down voter please leave a comment... Did I answer wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten` with `uniq`:

```
result["nodes"] = (result["nodes"] | result["edges"].flatten).uniq
```